# Log ELMAH errors based on the Database Environment In use

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, elmah, elmah.mvc

I am using ELMAH to log errors in my database. The problem I have here is that ELMAH always logs error in my Production database.
I have two connection strings in my database one for "Live Environment" and one for "Dev Environment".

```
<add name="LivePortal" connectionString="Data Source=Live-Database;Initial Catalog=LivePortal;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=LivePortalAccess;Password=Password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="DevConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=dev-database;Initial Catalog=DevPortal;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa-admin;Password=Password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />    
<add name="elmah-sqlserver" connectionString="Data Source=****;User ID=****;Password=****;Initial Catalog=****;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

<elmah>
<security allowRemoteAccess="false" />
<errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="elmah-sqlserver" />
```

The rest of the ELMAH code I have copied from the sites available with ELMAH connection. I have put all the required configurations, and it is logging error but only for Live DB.

I have checked other sites but none of the sites have any info if we use multiple database pointing to the environment being used i.e. Live or Dev.

Any help in this would be very great and helpful.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something like web.config transformations as described in this guide: [Use multiple logs for different environments](http://docs.elmah.io/use-multiple-logs-for-different-environments/).

Basically, you want the connection string pointing to the dev database in your web.config file and then add a web.release.config, web.production.config or whatever your naming schema is, pointing to the production database.

Answer (score 0):

You also have the option of using the same database for dev and prod and just changing the application name.

```
<errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="name" applicationName="dev/test/prod" />
```

This doesn't solve the problem of how to change the name or connectionstring programmatically, but offers another option.

As a side note, if you remove the application name, it will use the server name. In this way, dev's exceptions would be just visible to them and if you're dev/test/prod servers are different (not just different domains) then it would automatically be separated by server name.